# Getting Error on Using jQuery printElement Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xkw33bgu/1/) and let me know why I am getting following error on using jQuery printElement Plugin to print the `.table` ?

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined
```

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('button[type="submit"]').click(function () {
      $(this).closest('.panel').find('table').printElement();
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: The plugin you're using will require that you import the jQuery migrate add-on. It expects `$.browser` to exist, and in newer versions of the library it doesn't.

Comment: Go to [that author's Github repository](https://github.com/erikzaadi/jQuery.printElement) - the version of the library you're using appears to be quite out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in your jQuery version (2.x edge).

And the print script uses:

```
if ($.browser.opera || (/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())))
    mainOptions["printMode"] = 'popup';
```

So you change the jQuery version to an older one, that still uses `$.browser` support.
This was later discouraged as x-browser and x-device support doesn't work very well when conditionally program against the user agent string.

The whole idea changer started somewhere around jQuery version 1.8. Now it's advised to use support detection regardless which browser/device you're on.

Comment: Thanks Tim just a quick question? is there any option to print the element without "popup" window?

Comment: I believe you can make your popup window visible in the print.css? Not sure. Maybe take a look [here](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/)